# Group By seems to add inordinate amount of computation in a simple Postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a Postgres query as such:

```
select id,      
from ads_1 as a     
join ads_2 as b     
on a.id_key = b.id_key      
where b.date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-02'      
group by id     
order by id;
```

It's nothing fancy but works fine -- only takes about 3 minutes when querying a large database to return the result.

My question is, why does this slight modification to the above code cause the time for the query to more-than quadruple?

```
select id, b.ad_description     
from ads_1 as a     
join ads_2 as b     
on a.id_key = b.id_key      
where b.date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-02'      
group by id, b.ad_description       
order by id;
```

What is going on? The mere inclusion of one simple column of (albeit unique) information is bogging my query down. I am somehow asking Postgres to do a tremendously larger amount of work. For the life of me, I don't see how.

I'd like to preemptively apologize for not including any raw data. I'm hoping this simplified example of what I'm really facing is clear enough for some kind soul to make an enlightening comment.  I can say that I'm going over a million rows in each table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many rows do each of the result sets return?

Comment: The first query returns 6 rows in about 7 minutes, because there are only 6 unique ids, which refer to 6 unique clients.  However, there are a million text descriptions that are all unique text that belong to each of the advertisements. The description is unique: the id is not.

Comment: does the addition of the column mean you go from a 6 row result set to a million row result set?

Comment: I don't know -- I ran the query and included LIMIT 5 but the query didn't finish after a half an hour.  I'm letting it run for 2 hours now and I'll see if that indeed is the problem?

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: If your first query returns 6 rows your 2nd one will return the total number of rows those 6 id's have in table b, If all ad texts are unique then it will be: select count(*) from b where b.date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-02' and b.id in(clientid1, clientid2, ..., clientid6) rows. And it also has to return all the text blocks (instead of just 6 int values)

Comment: Can you explain what you want/expect the query to give you as a result? What question are you trying to get answered with this query?

Answer (score 0):

i think the size of the return set is the issue.  since your result set now has a millionish rows, that would explain the extra time (although it does seem excessive).  a couple of things.  first, the first column in the select is not bound to a range variable, it probably doesn't matter.  but, you might want to make it select b.id, b.ad_description instead of id, b.ad_description.  second, normally i use a group by when one of the columns is an aggregate that isn't in the group by statement, like a 'count()' or something. maybe i'm missing something, but, you might get the same result with:

```
select distinct b.id, b.ad_description
from ads_1 as a 
join ads_2 as b 
on a.id_key = b.id_key  
where b.date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-02'  
order by b.id, b.ad_description;
```

you might want to play with some of the numbers in the postgresql.conf file to beef up workspace/query space.

finally, i have this funny hunch that the order by and the group by matching might also help performance.

the LIMIT 5 wouldn't help much with performance, because the entire query would need to be finished before the first 5 rows would come out.

-g

Comment: It isn't excessive if the ad_description is a text block (unique ad-texts) and you are grouping on it. That is causing a massive amount of work to compare them all to see if they are equal or not